# Silverlight 3: Navigation page always aligns left!

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silly question.
How to center the content of navigation pages???

I've been following this tutorial:
http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=187319
(source code on page)

I tried setting the horizontalalignment to center on every damn thing possible but the content always ends up top left.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: OK found my mistake. I was using HorizontalAlignment=Stretch instead of HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch
===

<navigation:Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="navContent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"   Source="Search" Background="Gray"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found my mistake. I was using HorizontalAlignment=Stretch instead of HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch ===  – vidalsasoon (0 secs ago) [remove this comment]